# jquery jsonp callback has :1 at the end and it appears to be causing errors

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp, jquery-callback

I've got two cakephp installs that need to talk to each other. I'm using jquery to get the data - and even though it's a POST it's adding the data to the callback. It's not sensitive data so I'm not worried about that.

Jquery does add :1 to the end of the callback and I'm getting this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

The callback itself looks like this:
`?callback=jQuery111009052231097593904_1430459237196&id=1&subdomain=www&_=1430459237197:1`

and what is returned is valid json

the calling code is

```
function getProductForm(){
    var dataVals = {
        "id" : productId,
        "subdomain" : subdomain
    }

    console.log(dataVals);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        data: dataVals,
        success: loadProductFormPresets,
        url: 'http://abc.def.org/products/form/',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json",

        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        cache:false
    });
}
```

any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: by any chance, is the product id in this case 1?

Comment: Yep, it's id is in the main part of the callback string. With 2 variables why pick that one to append with a colon? And is that what is throwing the syntax error?